# search for multiple values in csv and return line in a list

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've got a CSV that contains multiple rows, one field is named "Market". What I'm trying to do is match each line with it's Market point of contact that I have in a list, but I can't quite seem to get it working.

So far I've tried the following:

```
PoC1 = ["Georgia", "Florida", "Alabama", "Mississippi"]
PoC2 = ["New York", "New Jersey", "Connecticut", "Pennsylvania"]
PoC3 = ["California", "Arizona", "Nevada", "Oregon"]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Markets.csv")
PoC1Markets = df[df['Market'] == PoC1]
PoC2Markets = df[df['Market'] == PoC2]
PoC3Markets = df[df['Market'] == PoC3]
```

But that didn't return anything. For reference, each line contains a latitude/longitude coordinate and an alphanumeric code that I'd expect to be returned. I'm trying to return each line that's pertinent to the market points of contact and send them each an email individually with their respective lines within the CSV. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First thing I notice is that you're not asking it to return anything

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pandas`, but `df[...] == ...` will be a boolean. So you're essentially saying `df` can be indexed both by strings (`'Market'`) and by booleans, which seems odd to me. Could you explain further what you're looking to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, doesn't necessarily need to be in Pandas. What I'm trying to do is search a CSV for strings that are specific to Points of Contact and return those strings in lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `pandas` and I might be misunderstanding your objective, but does something like this do what you're looking for? It would separate the records in the .csv file into the 3 buckets based on the value of the `Market` field.

```
import csv

PoC1 = ["Georgia", "Florida", "Alabama", "Mississippi"]
PoC2 = ["New York", "New Jersey", "Connecticut", "Pennsylvania"]
PoC3 = ["California", "Arizona", "Nevada", "Oregon"]

PoC1Markets = []
PoC2Markets = []
PoC3Markets = []

with open('Markets.csv','rb') as input:
  reader = csv.DictReader(input)
  for record in reader:
    market = record['Market']
    if market in PoC1:
      PoC1Markets.append(record)
    if market in PoC2:
      PoC2Markets.append(record)
    if market in PoC3:
      PoC3Markets.append(record)
  print(PoC1Markets)
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things that I see missing in the code provided but I think I can understand what you want to do. What I would like to tell you is to be sure to put proper columns names and index so you don't get confused and, as mentioned by @Paula Livingstone , I would also be sure that it is returning something.
That said, the best way to do something like that is to use the `isin` function, for example:

```
data = df[df[header[0]].isin(list[0])]
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: In that instance is `header` and `list` the actual header and list I'm searching for?